# Space above input, jQuery + Css3

Tags: jquery, css

Why when I click on the input, it creates a space above? ... how get rid of space?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/63/)

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" class="textinput" />
    <div class="info_form">Utilizează imagini de calitate: o imagine valorează cât o mie de cuvinte!</div>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="textinput" />
    <div class="info_form">Utilizează imagini de calitate: o imagine valorează cât o mie de cuvinte!</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".info_form").hide();
    jQuery("input").on("focus", function () {
        jQuery(".info_form").hide();
        jQuery(this).next('div.info_form').show();
    });

    jQuery(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!jQuery(e.target).is('input')) {
            jQuery(".info_form").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.textinput {
    width:40%;
    padding:6px;
    color:#666;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.4);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #eaeaea inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #eaeaea inset);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #eaeaea inset);
}
.info_form {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #d1d1d1;
    color:#333;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    padding:8px;
    top:21px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:280px;
    font-family:"Verdana", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.info_form:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 20%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    border-right-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused because `.info_form` has `position: relative`. You'd need to make it absolutely positioned.

```
.info_form {
    position: absolute;
}
```

However, that'll throw off the positioning.

Here's a solution where you wrap the input field and bubble in a container that's positioned relatively, and then adjust the z-index of the tooltip so it's on top.

### **Working Fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/DLnXs/)**

Adjust the `left` and `top` position of `.info_form` accordingly if you don't like how it's positioned.

Comment: Do not sit properly in the right input at the same level.

Comment: I assumed you would change the positioning to how you'd like it since the first example it wasn't properly aligning—your issue was to get rid of the spacing. I updated the demo so it should now properly align with the input.